# custom primaryKey not working laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, primary-key

Using Laravel 5.4.13, I have a model called Widget, where I set the primary key like this:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'widget_id';
```

The widgets table has a primary key column, int, auto-increment, named: widget_id.

Yet, when I try to update a record on the browser I get this error:

QueryException in Connection.php line 647:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `widgets` where `name` = est eum and `id` <> 3)

It still looks for a column called: id and not widget_id.

I found out it happens on this validation:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:40|unique:widgets,name,' .$widget->widget_id
    ]);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a closed issue but I encountered the same and I wish to contribute based on the new approach I have taken to fix the issue:

Laravel allows you to specify the foreignkey to be used in the relationship model using:

> return $this->hasOne('App\Model_name','foreign_key');

Once that is done, you can then extend the model and pull back associated records without having a trouble of specifying the unique fields.

To check more on this [follow documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:40|unique:widgets,name,' .$widget->widget_id.',widget_id'
]);
```

Comment: Thx dparoli, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

How did you actually added this new `widget_id`? And what have you done with the `id` field? If I understand well you want to remove `id` and replace it with `widget_id` right?

Keep in mind that you cannot have two auto increment field in the same table, and so on if you want to work properly you want `widget_id` to be AI. ( you can use `public $incrementing = false;` in your model but I dont recommend that )

I recommend removing the `id` and adding the `widget_id` with a new migration. To create a migration use the artisan command:

```
php artisan make:migration alter_user
```

Then add

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table(User::TABLE, function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->dropColumn('id');
    });
    Schema::table(User::TABLE, function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('widget_id');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table(User::TABLE, function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->dropColumn('widget_id');
    });
    Schema::table(User::TABLE, function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
    });
}
```

Note: you cannot add them to the same Schema.

Then you add `protected $primaryKey = 'widget_id';` to your model. Make sure you extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

It worked for me for a fresh laravel 5.4 installation, making the modifications on the user table. Hope it helps for you.

Comment: Thx, but I am not talking about the users table. I created the table (widgets) with a migration with a widget_id field instead of an id field. It is the only AI field in the table. There is no id column in this table only widget_id.

Comment: Here is the migration code:

    Schema::create('widgets', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('widget_id');
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->string('name')->unique();
                $table->string('slug')->unique();
                $table->timestamps();
                });

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Laravel 5.4 and actually the

```
protected $primaryKey = 'widget_id';
```

seems not to work anymore.
So what I did to solve the problem is re-write all the Models with the specific custom private and foreign keys.
For example read the docs for the one-to-one model about the foreign and local key here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Basically you have to define manually the foreign and local key on the models.
So if we have a Widget and User table with a one-to-one relationship, change the model as follows:
In the User table

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Widget', 'foreign_key_of_widget_table')
```

and in the widget model:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'foreign_key_of_users_table', 'local_key_of_widgets_table');
```

I had to re write everything in my project.
Hope this helps.